# Linking it to Adwords to Google Search Console + Cannot Verify http:// property

Tags: google-search-console, google-ads, site-verification

I have a problem with linking my Google Adwords to my Search Console and have tried to reverse engineer the issue to no avail.

1. Go to Adwords > Tools and Settings > Linked Accounts > Search Console > Click Details
2. The site URL that I am allowed to verify is http:// our account is a domain property on Search Console as well as having our https:// and http:// properties.
3. I cannot verify the property in adwords

**Recap**

- Domain property is verified
- `https://` url of the domain property is verified
- `https://subdomain` on the domain property is verified
- `http://` verified
- Google Adwords only gives me the option to connect to search console via the `http://` url
- I try to connect Adwords to search console and it cannot verify the property that is verified in search console!

Comment: When you say "as well as having our https:// property", does that mean that you have both the domain property and the prefix property for https verified in Google Search Console?

Comment: Do you get an error message from Google Search Console when trying to verify the http prefix property?

Answer (score 3):

**Google Adwords will not allow you to specify a protocol (http or https) when linking a "URL" to an Adwords account.** (I quote "URL" because that is the terminology used by Google in the Linked Accounts section in Adwords, which suggests at the outset a mis-match between Adwords and Google Search Console's *Domain Properties*.)

[image]

I had assumed that because I had a Domain Property set up in Google Search Console that this would appear in the list of domains to link under Adwords... no such luck.

For whatever reason, **Google does not display Domain Properties in the list of properties under your Google Search Console - it only lists URL Properties**.

However, if you enter a URL manually (e.g. "www.mydomain.com") this will actually link to the Domain Property in Google Search Console, and you can see this under the Associations section in Google Search Console.

[image]

As you've established though, https is apparently not an option. Any URL entered defaults to http.